# Install Module and remove all previous powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to install Module 'Azure' for powershell.

When I fire this

```
Install-Module 'Azure'
```

I Get the error message "WARNING: Version '4.2.0' of module 'Azure' is already installed at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure'. To install version '5.1.1' , run Install-Module and add the -Force
parameter. This command will install both version '4.2.0' and version '5.1.1'."

however i would rather have only one version than two that cause some conflict to other commands.

So I next do

```
Uninstall-Module 'Azure'
```

which succeeds , which I assume means all versions have been in installed.

then when I again try to fire Install-Module , the same error shows up.

How do I Clean up?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, maybe we can download Azure powershell 5.1.1 msi to install it on your windows.

We can download `PowerShell 5.1.1 MSI` from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v5.1.1-December2017/azure-powershell.5.1.1.msi).

Use this to install Azure PowerShell 5.1.1 will remove old version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To only add or remove modules by version, try using the -*Version options of the Install-Module cmdlet.

'learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1'

[-MinimumVersion ]
[-MaximumVersion ]

Answer (score 0):

Used this to uninstall old version of AzureRM modules:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable Azure*  | Group-Object -Property Name | Where {$_.Count -gt 1}  | foreach  {$_.Group | sort  Version -Descending | select -Last 1} | Uninstall-Module -Force
```

Comment: This doesn't work all the time (because the Version field is typed as a string, and ("1.9.0" -gt "1.10.0")) Something like this works better:

Get-Module -ListAvailable Azure*  | Group-Object -Property Name | Where {$_.Count -gt 1}  | foreach  {$_.Group | sort {[Version]$_.Version} -Descending | select -Last 1} | Uninstall-Module -Force